# How do I enable Bluetooth with my Qualcomm Atheros adapter?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, pci-express

I have a wireless/BlueTooth PCIe card (Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222) in my computer but only the wireless part is enabled. I got the drivers and installed them, but nothing changed. I searched for it in Devices in the Windows 10 settings and BlueTooth wasn't listed.

[image: Wireless Adapter connected with two antennas, notice the on LED vs the off LED]
[image: Front of Card]
[image: Very Front of Card]
[image: End of Card]
[image: Back of Card]

Comment: Have you actually verified that your AR5BWB222 has a Bluetooth module installed?  In the hundreds of parts I have seen like the AR5BWB222, the Bluetooth functionality, by design is seperate from the 802.11 functionality in that its an entirely seperate and most of the time optional module.  This means if you don't have a module that with markings clearly indicating Bluetooth functionality then your system does not have said hardware module.  These cards are by designed expandable, so a single card can be sold, for multiple purposes.

Comment: @Ramhound It says BT_LED (it looks like ST on the photo, but I have verified it says BT) on the first port. I presume that stands for Bluetooth and that it is in the card. How would I find out if Bluetooth is actually in the card?

Comment: "How would I find out if Bluetooth is actually in the card?" - You look at the physical card?  I figured my comment was obvious in this capacity.

Comment: @Ramhound In that case, it is.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for the BT device? Does the BT device show up in Device Manager?

Comment: @Ramhound I see the device under Network Adapters. I went to their website and installed the drivers for the Atheros card.

Comment: The BT device should not be located under network adaptors.  The network adaptor and the BT device should be their own devices.

Comment: @Ramhound I only see the Wireless Adapter listing.

Comment: Have you veiified the module is properly installed on the card itself?  Is the BT module an installable part, due to hardware differences and the age of the card itself, pictures of PCIe card itself are hard to come across.

Comment: @Ramhound I have supplied pictures of the card. I do not know where to find the Bluetooth component on it. I had a picture of the back but it was 0.08 MB over the limit. It just contained some numbers, such as the serial number.

Comment: The very first question I asked was if you verified you had a BT module installed.  You indicated in your response to my question, that you had indeed verified, you had a module that specifically indicated Bluetooth support.  I am looking at the picture of the PCIe card you have installed, I see no indication the module you have installed, has BT support.

Comment: [GC-WB300D Drivers](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4135#dl).  If you install the drivers, and the device still does not show up, then more information on the history of this card is required.  It appears to be [different](http://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/product/2/4135/5761_big.jpg) then the pictures Gigabyte offers, the silver metatallic object, is the BT module.  At least thats the case on the M.2 WiFi/BT card I have.  If the card is used, then its very likely, you didn't get all the parts for it.

Comment: @Ramhound I got the entire PC new back in 2012. I have been upgrading it since.

Comment: I don't think I even bothered to ask, did the BT ever work?

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot recall. I just dug out my antennas today after years, so I do not remember. After installing the BT driver and restarting my PC, it did not show up unfortunately.

Comment: If that is the case, I am going, you don't actually have a BT device.  If you feel confortable you can, remove the mini-PCIe card, and see what it says on the other side.

Comment: @Ramhound I posted the picture of the back of the card. What do I look for on the back?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you plugging in the USB that's on the board? The BT is powered by the onboard USB and not powered through the PCI passthrough.

Comment: I think Ramhound meant the back of the little mini-PCIe card (disconnect antennas inner cables, remove two screws, unplug the card from its slot) – but it may not be necessary. [This site](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4302#ov) says BT should be there (unless the original mini-PCIe card was switched to the one without it, yet your AR5BWB222 should have it, original or not). Hiiambo may be right. [The manual](http://download.gigabyte.ru/manual/mb_manual_gc-wb300d(wb150)_1.1_e.pdf) says you should connect the USB cable so it's there for a reason.

Comment: Where did you get the driver from and what version is it? What is your computer model? Have you tried switching off firewall and other security software? If you have VPN software installed then see [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3084164).

Comment: @hiiambo Yeah, it is plugged in.

Comment: @harrymc I got the driver from Ramhound's comment above. My computer model? I do not have any VPNs on and it is not my security.

Comment: I mean what is your computer, or at least what is the motherboard.

Comment: @harrymc It is a Gigabyte X79-UP4.

Comment: The Gigabyte website doesn't have any useful drivers, so it is up to Windows or you. If BT does not work, then the drivers you use are incorrect or you don't have a BT stack installed. Questions: (1) Do you know if a BT stack installed with the drivers you are using? (2) In Control Panel / Device Manager, do you have a "Bluetooth" entry?

Comment: @harrymc 1. I do not know if BT stack is installed. 2. There is no Bluetooth entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the Qualcomm Atheros driver suite.

https://www.atheros-drivers.com/download-driver-nr-267-for-atheros-AR3011-and-Windows7.html

Follow these steps to install this software:

- goto start right click "Computer"
- click manage
- open Device manager,  you will see Bluetooth Radios
- right click on the USB Bluetooth module
- click properties
- click update driver
- click search manually
- click ill choose the file
- select, Bluetooth radios from list
- on left pane click MICROSOFT CORPORATION
- install the driver in the right pane

Now your Bluetooth will broadcast and you will be able to pair.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the usb header cable to power the Bluetooth. Which should have come with hardware. You see that plug in socket on the card. The cable plugs into it and your motherboard. Just google wireless adapters with Bluetooth function to see what it looks like. The pci express slot can only power 1 device. you have to have the bluetooth cable to power the Bluetooth. I found that out doing research online when i had the same problem. just getting the cable was impossible for me. Just buy another card and make sure the Bluetooth cable is included.

Comment: This was the exact problem I had. Spend so long trying to install drivers manually, plugging it in different PCI on the motherboard etc. Feel like a total dumbass - next time will look at the instruction manual XD

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

I suggest you to run the Hardware and device troubleshooter and check. The Hardware Troubleshooter is an automated tool which checks the hardware on the computer for any known issues and provides the details on how to fix them. Follow these steps to run the troubleshooter.

a) Press “Windows Logo” + “W” keys from the keyboard.

b) Type “Troubleshooting” in the search bar and press “Enter”.

c) In the “Troubleshooting” window, click on “View All” on the left pane.

d) Click on “Hardware and Devices”.

e) Click on “Advanced” and then click on “Run as Administrator”.

f) Click “Next” and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the troubleshooting process.

If the issue persists, I suggest you to check the status of Bluetooth service on the computer.

**Method 2:**

I suggest you to start the Bluetooth service and set it to Automatic:

a. Go to the Start screen.

b. Type “Services.msc” without quotes and press Enter.

c. Right click on Bluetooth support service and click on Properties.

d. Set the Startup type as Automatic and then click Start under Service status.

e. Click on OK.

If the issue persists you can try the following steps and check if it resolves the issue.

**Method 3:**

I suggest you to try the following steps.

a. Open Control Panel by clicking the Windows + X,

b. In the Control Panel search box, type Bluetooth, and then click Change Bluetooth settings.

c. In theBluetooth Settings dialog box, click the Options tab and do any of the following:

To make your computer discoverable to Bluetooth enabled devices, select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer.

To allow you to add Bluetooth enabled devices to your computer, select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer.

To be notified when a Bluetooth enabled device is trying to connect to your computer, select the check box for Alert me when a new Bluetooth device wants to connect.

**Method 4:**

If the issue still persists, I suggest you to uninstall the Bluetooth driver and install the latest driver on the computer.

Comment: I have tried the other Methods but nothing happened so far. With Method 3, I do not see Bluetooth in my Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

The Atheros cards have two of their pins dedicated to sometimes deactivating Bluetooth, these are pin 51 and pin 5. If you delete this pin (preferably 51) maybe Bluetooth works. My notebook does not support Bluetooth or at least so it seems. Since eliminating pin 51 I managed to make the Bluetooth work with an Atheros AR9485 card.

I suggest that you remove the pin from the adapter and not directly on the card very carefully.

Pin 51 identified:

[image]